# Displacement Loading Abaqus

Tags: boundary, abaqus, disp

I want to write a subroutine DISP in Abaqus in Fortran for uni-axial extension of a 3D cylinder.

I want to apply displacement loading in one surface of the cylinder by a smooth function.

The function: d(t)=dmax(t^3+2t^4+3t^5)

How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: `disp` is one of the simpler subroutines in abaqus. can you clarify where you are stuck?

Comment: Just how to put the maximum displacement (dmax) as a function of time. 


SUBROUTINE DISP(U,KSTEP,KINC,TIME,NODE,NOEL,JDOF,COORDS)

C

INCLUDE 'ABA_PARAM.INC'

C

DIMENSION U(3),TIME(2),COORDS(3)

C

"user coding to define U"


RETURN

END

Comment: can you not do this with an amplitude? without having to resort to a user subroutine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this by creating an amplitude and writing your equation, or generate a table of time and displacement somewhere else (Matlab) and import it.